# Sizing div within flexbox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to size a div according to the page and column size. The div must always be a square, regardless of its width. What I mean by that is:

When it's set in a row, it takes up the amount of space it's allocated. In this case, the text took 50% of the space. The remaining 50% must be taken up by the square div.

When it's set to a column (stacked on smaller screens), it takes up the amount of space it's allocated. In this case, the square div is the full width of the screen.

```
div.layout-1-img{
    flex: 1;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 5em;
    height:5em;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/violetto/ngbwrsqv/)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand: 
you have a div that will contain the text you want, but this div width and height change.
You want the outerdiv to always be a SQUARE regardless of the page width, but still have the text div inside.

Possible Solution:

Create an outer div:

```
.outerDiv{
display: block;
position: absolute;
background-color: gray;
padding: 10px;   // Specify the padding value if you want
}
```

Then using jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

       //Get the text div height and width
    var height = $('#textdiv').height();
    var width = $('#textdiv').width();

// increase the size of height or width by 
// How much taller you want the back to be compared to text div.
//In this example I'm increasing the background by a factor of 2

height = height *2;
width = width *2;

    //Compare to see which one is largest.
// Then change css of background to correspond to the correct size

if(height>width){
$('.outerDiv').height(height);
$('.outerDiv').width(height);
}else{
$('.outerDiv').height(width);
$('.outerDiv').width(width);
}

    });
```